# Array of different classes objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object

in class Baza i need to make an array, which will contain objects from classes ZadanieTekst, ZadanieNumer, Zadanie4Odp. How can i achieve this ?

```
class Zadanie
{
    protected:
        string tresc;
};

class Zadanie4Odp : private Zadanie
{
    private:
    string a,b,c,d;
    string poprawna;
    public:
    Zadanie4Odp(string tresc1,string a1,string b1,string c1,string d1,string pop)
    {
        tresc=tresc1;
        a=a1;
        b=b1;
        c=c1;
        d=d1;
        poprawna=pop;
    }
};

class ZadanieNumer : private Zadanie
{
    private:
        int poprawna;
    public:
    ZadanieNumer()
    {
    }
    ZadanieNumer(string tresc1,int pop)
    {
        tresc=tresc1;
        poprawna=pop;
    }
};

class ZadanieTekst : private Zadanie
{
    private:
        string poprawna;
    public:
        ZadanieTekst(string tresc1,string pop)
        {
             tresc=tresc1;
             poprawna=pop;
        }
};

class Baza
{
//here must be array of objects
};
```

Im doing it for my school project, and its the problem i can't work out.
Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: why was it private access specifier for inheritance how will the child class be able to access the parent class data fields

Comment: A horrible thought, this could be done with variant records, Pascal style instead of using inheritance since the fields are known in advance.

Answer (score -2):

I think that, without putting too much work using std::unique_ptr or std::array, something like this would be useful:

```
#include <vector>

...

class Baza
{
    public:
        std::vector<Zadanie*> my_vector;

};

...

int main(void)
{
    Baza my_baza;

    // Remember to properly destroy objects if you plan to
    // use this approach  without memory leaks!
    my_baza.my_vector.push_back(new ZadanieTekst(//Insert Params//));
    my_baza.my_vector.push_back(new ZadanieNumer(//Insert Params//));
    my_baza.my_vector.push_back(new Zadanie4Odp(//Insert Params//));

    ...

    return 0;
}
```